# Concept of persistence store using RDBMS

Tags: ignite

Im new to ignite and found to be a good product and trying to evaluate it to find how it help my organisation goals.

My primary question is about persistence using an RDBMS system.

1) Can I connect multiple mysql server to a cluster, this question came from the thought If I cant store the entire data in a single mysql instance.

2) If I can connect mysql server for persistence, then each server will hold the same data or will be distributed across the cluster and combine everything to make the full dataset?

Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. You can have multiple data sources. It can map a cache in Ignite to a table in a legacy database like MySQL. [See the documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store) on how to configure that
2. That depends on how you configure your cache. By default it would be partitioned, where the data is distributed around the cluster. You can also have a replicated cache where the same data is copied to each node

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think we have sharding of backing SQL database. Unless you devise your own sublass of `CacheJdbcPojoStore`, one cache will be written to a single backing SQL table.
2. All nodes usually store data to a single underlying SQL database, even when each node only holds a fraction of data itself.